# How to initialize javascript when the user scrolls?

Tags: javascript, overrides

I need the javascript to load after the user scrolls. Right now I have a .phtml file that just has this,

```
<div id="razoyo-gtm-user-code" style="display:none;" data-mage-init='{ "razoyoGlobalUserCode": { "pageType": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getPageType()); ?>"} }'>
```

Which loads razoyoGlobalUserCode as soon as the page is done loading. But I need the file to load *after* the user scrolls. So I've tried this:

```
<script>  
    var razoyo = document.createElement('div');
    razoyo.id = 'razoyo-gtm-user-code';
    razoyo.style = 'display:none';    
    razoyo.setAttribute("data-mage-init", '{ "razoyoTest": { "pageType": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getPageType()); ?>"} }');

    document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {   
    document.head.appendChild(razoyo);
    });
</script>
```

However this doesnt fix the issue at all. If someone has any advice on what I can do I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var secret = false,
        testTop = $('#test').offset().top,
    testHeight = $('#test').height(),
    scrlTop;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scrlTop > testTop && scrlTop < testTop+testHeight){
    if(!secret){
        console.log('call me once please');
      secret = true;
    }   
  }else{
    secret = false;     
  }
});
```

Comment: replace your code with this one...